# How to find where a parametric curve overlaps itself, problem with calculation?

Tags: equation-solving, parametric-functions

[image]

This should work? But it is giving me the wrong t values

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get intersection values from a parametric graph?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/33947/how-to-get-intersection-values-from-a-parametric-graph). See also: [Finding intersections of two parametric curves](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/84566/27951) and [How to get accurate intersection point value of Parametric equation?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/170617/27951) and [Intersection of two similar parametric curves](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/145328/27951).

Comment: Did any of the answers worked for you? There are **[things to do after your question is answered](https://wolfr.am/v57DB3p4)**. It's a good idea to stay vigilant for some time, as better approaches may come later improving over previous replies. Also, experienced users may point alternatives, caveats or limitations. New users should **test answers before [voting](https://wolfr.am/v57ItzJq)** and **wait 24 hours before [accepting](https://wolfr.am/v57LwTXD)** the best one, but now may be time for you to accept one. Participation is essential for the site, please do your part.

Answer (score 7):

```
r[t_] := {6 Cos[ 2.9 Pi t], Cos[3.5 Pi t] + 5 t};

pp = ParametricPlot[r[t], {t, 0, 1} ];
pt = First @ Graphics`Mesh`FindIntersections[pp];

Show[pp, Graphics @ {Red, PointSize[Large], Point @ pt}, 
 PlotLabel -> Style[Row[{"intersection = ", pt}], 16]]
```

[image]

To get the same result using `FindRoot`, we can use the approach from [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/10288/125) to (1) add the constraints `t2 > t1` and (2) randomly change the starting values until no error message is issued by `FindRoot` :

```
constraints = 0 < t1 < 1 && t2 > t1;
startingvals = {RandomReal[], RandomReal[]};
While[err == Quiet@Check[
 sol = FindRoot[1 - Boole[constraints] + Boole[constraints] (r[t2] - r[t1]), 
       Transpose[{{t1, t2}, startingvals}]], err], 
  startingvals = {RandomReal[], RandomReal[]};];
r[t1] /. sol
```

> {-0.320402, 3.3467}

To get multiple intersections remove `First` in definition of `pt` above:

```
pp = ParametricPlot[r[t], {t, 0, 10}];
pt = Graphics`Mesh`FindIntersections[pp];
Labeled[Show[pp, Graphics@{Red, PointSize[Large], Point@pt}, AspectRatio -> 1], 
 Style[Column[{"intersections", MatrixForm@pt}], 16], Left]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
r[t_] := {6 Cos[29 Pi t/10], Cos[7 Pi t/2] + 5 t};

ParametricPlot[r[t], {t, 0, 1}, 
 ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, t}, ColorData["Rainbow"][t]], 
 PlotLegends -> BarLegend["Rainbow"]]
```

[image]

Using the colors to determine the initial estimates,

```
sol = FindRoot[{(r[t0][[1]]) == (r[t1][[1]]), (r[t0][[2]]) == (r[
       t1][[2]])}, {{t0, 1/2}, {t1, 9/10}}, WorkingPrecision -> 15]

(* {t0 -> 0.511377264145361, t1 -> 0.867933080682225} *)
```

Verifying,

```
r[t0] == r[t1] /. sol

(* True *)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you didn't have a vast knowledge of all the internal functions provided by Mathematica then you might try a more brute force approach.

Trying a variety of starting values for t1 and t2 seems to usually come up with the same value for t1 and t2. Thus it looks like `FindRoot` might not have sufficiently good starting values to be able to find different t1 and t2 that give you your intersection. But from your graph you have a pretty good estimate of `r[t]` so lets look for points near that intersection and which have a substantially different values for t.

```
rt[t_] := {6 Cos[2.9 Pi t], Cos[3.5 Pi t] + 5 t, t};
Select[Table[rt[t], {t, 0, 1, .001}], 3.2<#[[2]]<3.4 && -1<#[[1]]<0 &]
```

which gives us

```
{...
 {-0.067857, 3.39995, 0.516},
 {-0.0508932, 3.31707, 0.863},
 ...
}
```

which hints that t1 ~= .516 and t2 ~= .863 so we try

```
r[t_] := {6 Cos[2.9 Pi t], Cos[3.5 Pi t] + 5 t};
sol = FindRoot[r[t1] - r[t2], {{t1, .516}, {t2, .863}}]
```

and that correctly finds two distinct t1 and t2 for your problem.

Answer (score 2):

NSolve can do the job, if you use rationalized parameters. Even Solve can do it, gives Root expression.

```
r[t_] = {6 Cos[29/10 Pi t], Cos[35/10 Pi t] + 5 t};

eq1 = And @@ Thread[r[t1] == r[t2]] && 0 < t1 < t2 < 1

eq2 = eq1 // TrigToExp // Simplify

(*   E^(-(29/10) I \[Pi] t2) + E^((29 I \[Pi] t2)/10) == 
     E^(-(29/10) I \[Pi] t1) + E^((29 I \[Pi] t1)/10) && 
     E^(-(7/2) I \[Pi] t2) + E^((7 I \[Pi] t2)/2) + 10 t2 == 
     E^(-(7/2) I \[Pi] t1) + E^((7 I \[Pi] t1)/2) + 10 t1 && 
   0 < t1 < t2 < 1      *)

nsol = NSolve[eq2, {t1, t2}, WorkingPrecision -> 30] // Chop // 
    Simplify[#, t1 \[Element] Reals && t2 \[Element] Reals] &

(*   {{t1 -> 0.511377264145361554521949670476, 
       t2 -> 0.867933080682224652374602053662}}   *)

sol = Solve[eq2, {t1, t2}] // Chop // 
       Simplify[#, t1 \[Element] Reals && t2 \[Element] Reals] &

(*   {{t1 -> Root[{-29 (-1 + (-1)^(1/29)) (1 + (-1)^(1/29)) (1 + (-1)^(
      2/29)) (1 - (-1)^(1/29) + (-1)^(2/29)) (1 + (-1)^(
      1/29) + (-1)^(2/29)) (1 + (-1)^(4/29)) (1 - (-1)^(
      2/29) + (-1)^(4/29)) (1 - (-1)^(4/29) + (-1)^(8/29)) - 
   400 E^((7 I \[Pi] #1)/2) + 29 E^(7 I \[Pi] #1) - 
   29 E^(7/29 I \[Pi] (-20 + 29 #1)) + 
   580 E^((7 I \[Pi] #1)/2) #1 &, 
 0.511377264145361554521949670476156189687360774384 + 
  0.*10^-49 I}], 
t2 -> 40/29 - 
  Root[{-29 (-1 + (-1)^(1/29)) (1 + (-1)^(1/29)) (1 + (-1)^(
       2/29)) (1 - (-1)^(1/29) + (-1)^(2/29)) (1 + (-1)^(
       1/29) + (-1)^(2/29)) (1 + (-1)^(4/29)) (1 - (-1)^(
       2/29) + (-1)^(4/29)) (1 - (-1)^(4/29) + (-1)^(8/29)) - 
    400 E^((7 I \[Pi] #1)/2) + 29 E^(7 I \[Pi] #1) - 
    29 E^(7/29 I \[Pi] (-20 + 29 #1)) + 
    580 E^((7 I \[Pi] #1)/2) #1 &, 
  0.511377264145361554521949670476156189687360774384 + 
   0.*10^-49 I}]}}   *)
```

Answer (score 2):

Without special knowledge NMinimize solves the problem straight forward:

```
NMinimize[{1/(t2 - t1)^2 (*force t1!=t2*), r[t1] == r[t2], 0 < t1 < t2 < 1}, {t1, t2}]    
(*{7.86584, {t1 -> 0.511377, t2 -> 0.867933}}*)
```